# Minimize $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ subject to constraint $(x-1)^3-y^2=0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Minimize $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ subject to constraint $(x-1)^3-y^2=0$.  This was presented as an example for which the method of Lagrange multipliers fails to identify the minima at $(1,0)$.  My issue is without reference to the plot, how would you find and classify the point $(1,0)$?

Answer (score 1):

For the condition $(x-1)^3=y^2$ we have $x\geq1$ and $(1,0)$ can not be a point of a local extreme,

but in $(1,0)$ our $f$ gets a minimal value.

The condition was $(x-1)^2=y^3$.

For this condition:

Let $g(x)=x^2+\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}.$

Thus, $g'(x)=2x+\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{x-1}}.$

We see that $g'(x)\rightarrow+\infty$ for $x\rightarrow1^+$ and $g'(x)\rightarrow-\infty$ for $x\rightarrow1^-$.

Id est, $(1,0)$ is a local minimum point of $g$.

Comment: Ah I guess that will suffice.  Btw how would you identify $(1,0)$ in the first place as a point to be tested?

Comment: @helios321 It's a point of the global minimum.

Comment: Say again?  What I mean is, to test for critical points we set the gradient of the lagrangian to $0$ but that doesn't work here to identify $(1,0)$.

Comment: @helios321 In this point the function is not differentiable, but it's a point of the global minimum.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me.  Let me rephrase as a more general question.  If finding critical points fail using Lagrange multipliers, how do you go about finding points that may still be minima or maxima?  In this case you have a curve in the plane, but why decide to test $(1,0)$?  Although you could spot it from function $g$ for our problem, in general what is the method for finding such points?

Comment: We need always to check a border of the domain. In our case it's the point $(1,0)$. Also, we need to check points where our function is not differentiable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105393/discussion-between-helios321-and-michael-rozenberg).

Comment: Hmm.  So for a segment $[a,b]$ the boundary is obviously $a$ and $b$ for which we check their values to test for extremum.  But in this curve its not clear to me why $(1,0)$ is a border/boundary for the level set defined by $(x-1)^3-y^2=0$.  And when you say check where function is not differentiable you are referring to $f$ the function we want to min/max right?

Comment: @helios321 $y^2\geq0$, which gives $x\geq1$ and the point $(1,0)$. I meant the function $g(x)=x^2+\sqrt{(x-1)^3}.$ In your previous example $g(x)=x^2+\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2},$ which is not differentiable in $x=1$, but the domain it's $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrange multiplier's technique can be successfully applied when the involved functions are class $\mathcal{C}^1$. The function used as restriction

$$
g(x,y)=(x-1)^3-y^2=0
$$
does not pertain to $\mathcal{C}^1$ because it's implicit derivative is discontinuous at $x = 1$ as can be easily verified because

$$
y' = \frac 32\sqrt{x-1}
$$

then at this point can occur problems with the method.

Concluding, the assertion " This was presented as a counter example to the method of Lagrange multipliers" is not correct because the methot cannot be applied.

Comment: You are right.  Bad expression.